# ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING : Gulp not working with React app

Tags: reactjs, gulp, gulp-watch

All of a sudden, I am getting this error in my console. I don't get any error while I perform gulp on my project and I successfully get my Bundle.js as my output file.I googled it but didn't find anything useful

[image: Error coming in Inspect Element]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because of adBlocker extension in firefox .I disabled it and then error din't come. Whereas in chrome I had to uninstall all of my extensions to get rid of this error .